# Tarjan's strong connected component wrong or my code is wrong?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, graph, strongly-connected-graph

I am trying to implement Tarjan's strongly connected graph algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm), here is my code and I am confused why vertex `4` and vertex `5` are also output as strongly connected component?

I am using a very simple diagram only have 5 nodes to test. My code is written in Python 2.7.

```
from collections import defaultdict
class SccGraph:
    def __init__(self, vertex_size):
        self.out_neighbour = defaultdict(list)
        self.vertex = set()
        self.visited = set()
        self.index = defaultdict(int)
        self.low_index = defaultdict(int)
        self.global_index = 0
        self.visit_stack = []
        self.scc = []
    def add_edge(self, from_node, to_node):
        self.vertex.add(from_node)
        self.vertex.add(to_node)
        self.out_neighbour[from_node].append(to_node)
    def dfs_graph(self):
        for v in self.vertex:
            if v not in self.visited:
                self.dfs_node(v)
    def dfs_node(self, v):
        # for safe protection
        if v in self.visited:
            return
        self.index[v] = self.global_index
        self.low_index[v] = self.global_index
        self.global_index += 1
        self.visit_stack.append(v)
        self.visited.add(v)
        for n in self.out_neighbour[v]:
            if n not in self.visited:
                self.dfs_node(n)
                self.low_index[v] = min(self.low_index[v], self.low_index[n])
            elif n in self.visit_stack:
                self.low_index[v] = min(self.low_index[v], self.index[n])
        result = []
        if self.low_index[v] == self.index[v]:
            w = self.visit_stack.pop(-1)
            while w != v:
                result.append(w)
                w = self.visit_stack.pop(-1)
            result.append(v)
            self.scc.append(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = SccGraph(5)
    # setup a graph 1->2->3 and 3 -> 1 which forms a scc
    # setup another two edges 3->4 and 4->5
    g.add_edge(1,2)
    g.add_edge(2,3)
    g.add_edge(3,1)
    g.add_edge(3,4)
    g.add_edge(4,5)
    g.dfs_graph()
    print g.scc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every single vertex is strongly connected. If it does not belong to any bigger strongly connected subgraph, then it is already strong component. So both your implementation and Tarjan's algorithm are fine. (I didn't check if you have any other mistakes).

Comment: Vote up. Confused why single vertex is strongly connected? I think by definition, if a vertex has an edge point to itself, then it is strongly connected?

Comment: You can reach a vertex v from itself. So it is strongly connected.

Comment: Thanks Saeed, even without an explicit edge to point to itself? I think it might be a grey area in graph whether a vertex in a graph can be reached by itself?

Comment: @Lin, the point of reachability as its name says is to visit that vertex. So when we are at the vertex you don't need to make any extra move to reach it. E.g. we almost always say the distance of a vertex from itself is zero.

Comment: More explicitly, usually in graph theory, a single vertex is called trivial strong component, if it does not belong to any strong component with at least 2 vertices.

Comment: BTW, if you find any bugs in my code, please let me know.